# Powershell out-file csv delimiting

Tags: powershell, csv, delimiter, robocopy

I have a powershell command using robocopy to list files. I am trying to output to csv but it does not separate the columns as needed. I get two columns where there should be 5. is there a delimiter parameter for `out-file` csv?

Here is the current code:

```
robocopy .\Documents\ NULL /L /S /V /E /BYTES /FP /NC /NDL /XJ /TS /R:1 /W:2 | Out-File -Append -FilePath "c:\beehive_20150608.csv" -Encoding ASCII
```

I tried `export-csv` and it only brings back the string length of the path.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Out-File` in your case simply writes output of `robocopy` into a file, so unless `robocopy` formats it properly you will not get proper CSV as output. `Export-Csv` requires list of objects as input, while output of robocopy is list of strings. I suggest you describe what you try to achieve in detail first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you need to list all files under some folder. You can use `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` for that instead of `robocopy`, filter only files with `Where-Object` then pick only properties you want with `Select-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem .\Documents -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer}| Select-Object -property LastWriteTime,Length,FullName | Export-Csv aaa.csv
```

If you need to use `robocopy` you may try parsing it's output:

```
robocopy .\Documents\ NULL /L /S /V /E /BYTES /FP /NC /NDL /XJ /TS /R:1 /W:2 /njh /njs | Where-Object {$_ -match '^\s*([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+(.*?)\s*$'} | ForEach-Object { new-object PSObject -property @{Length=$matches[1];Date=$matches[2];Time=$matches[3];Name=$matches[4]}} | Export-Csv aaa.csv
```

It's ugly, but should do what you need. I added `/njh` and `/njs` arguments to your command line to suppress `robocopy`'s header and footer, `Where-Object` removes non-matching (empty) lines and `ForEach-Object` creates object with named properties using `$Matches` created by `-match` operator used in `Where-Object`.

Comment: you are correct I am trying to get a listing of all the sub folders and objects in a directory. will Get-ChildItem support path names longer than 260 characters? I thought only robocopy is able to support paths and filenames up to 36,000.

Comment: You are right, `Get-ChildItem` is not able to handle long path names.

Comment: I appreciate the snippet of code. I might be able to use that for other tasks.

Comment: Updated to have it handle spaces in paths correctly